# Should I use serialized data to store it in my DB for invoice?

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, store

I need to organize invoice function in my project.
I need to store a lot of products. This products will be unique every time because it should records the current price, name and etc.

So I wanted to create an array for that. And I wanted to use serialize to store it in one record of DB (MySQL).

But I heard that I shouldn't use this method to store the data.
I want to receive a suggestion from you. How can I store it in another way?

P.S. I also use Laravel in this project and I use Eloquent model system.

Thanks a lot!

Update. I need to use this schema:

```
ID: [For system usage]
Invoice ID: [For tax service usage]
User ID:
Product List:
    Name:
    Price:
    Quantity:
    Reminder:
Notes for invoice:
```

Comment: Please post some sample data, if you are able.

Comment: This portal is for question and answers not for general suggestions my dear friend. Please let us know if you have any thing specific.

Comment: @EricHauenstein I added some data to the question.

Comment: you may want to create a table "invoice", and a second "ordered_products", and have a 1-n relation between them.  Storing as serialized string is not the least bit elegant, but in case you need that for backup or anything else like "must store but will hardly ever use", serialization might be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use 'invoice' table with 1-n relation with my current table for that.

Thanks to everybody!